# What do we do with questions that I don't think there is an answer to?

Tags: discussion

[Peter](https://chess.stackexchange.com/users/5784/peter) has asked a good set of questions asking for complete games that end in interesting positions, namely

- [Complete game Ojanen - Ridala , Helsinki 1959](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/9040/complete-game-ojanen-ridala-helsinki-1959)
- [Complete game Szabo-Groszpeter, Kecskemet 1984](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/8876/complete-game-szabo-groszpeter-kecskemet-1984)
- [Complete game troitzky - vogt?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/9002/complete-game-troitzky-vogt)

Myself and other users researched these questions with no success using the following means:

- Searching databases
- Using Google
- Searching chess books
- Emailing the author of websites that @Peter links to

My own conclusion is that these complete games are no longer accessible.

This raises the question, **what do we do with questions where there are no known answers?** Do we:

- Post an *answer* detailing the research undertaken, and say there are no results?
- Post in *comments* detailing the research undertaken, and say there are no results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it depends on how much work you have done. If you've just done a quick search of Chessbase and one or two other databases then a comment is suitable.

If you have done extensive research then the greater space and formatting possibilities (links, quotes, lists etc.) of an answer would be better. An answer also allows comments from other users specific to your answer to be more clearly attached to your response.